# Unknown server tag 'CR:CrystalReportViewer'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, crystal-reports

I am working on VS2010, Crystal Reports. While compiling my code I am getting below error:

```
Unknown server tag 'CR:CrystalReportViewer'
```

I have added reference in the web.config file as:

```
    <assemblies>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
            <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Viewing.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
< /assemblies>
```

In my aspx page i have registered following:

```
< %@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" Namespace="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine" TagPrefix="CR" %>

< %@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" Namespace="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource" TagPrefix="CR" %>
```

Could you please suggest what i am missing?

Comment: Have they been working before and then all of the sudden this happened? Or are you trying to get it up and working for the first time?

Comment: the solution had been assigned to me yesterday only, it was written in VS 2005, I have migrated to 2010 and now i am facing this compilation error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you only need to register this guy...

```
<%@ Register assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" tagprefix="CR" %>
```

that and make sure you installed the [VS 2010 version of crystal](http://www.sap.com/solutions/sap-crystal-solutions/query-reporting-analysis/sapcrystalreports-visualstudio/downloads/index.epx). It doesn't come with VS anymore...

Comment: np, I was literally working on a project with a functioning viewer page when I saw this question on my rss feed. :)

Comment: This version of VS2010 NOT Available in Crystal report page